# Definition for finite and infinite zeros of a matrix pencil

Tags: matrix-equations, control-theory, matrix-pencil

I'm currently studying generalized linear systems of the form

$Ey^{\prime}(t) = Ay(t) + Bu(t)$

with controllability pencil pencil $\left[ sE-A \quad B \right]$. In [here](http://ntur.lib.ntu.edu.tw/bitstream/246246/2007041910032291/1/00271394.pdf) it is said that $(E,A,B)$
is controllable if the controllability pencil has
no finite or infinite zeros. But I miss a definition for infinite and finite zeros and I couldn't find a fiting one.

Comment: Where did you see this? Please provide a reference.

Comment: Can you provide another reference, because for me it says that the added link points to an insecure file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, this is not defined in the paper and it is also not defined in many of the papers I have looked at.

In any way, a finite zero for the pencil $\left[ sE-A \quad B \right]$ is a value for $s\in\mathbb{C}$ for which $\left[ sE-A \quad B \right]$ has a rank drop. On the other hand, an infinite zero is when $\left[E \quad B \right]$ has a rank drop.

To formulate a more self-contained answer, let us define the descriptor system $(E,A,B)$ as

$$
E\dot{x}=Ax+Bu\qquad\qquad(1)
$$

The system $(E,A)$ is said to be regular if $\det(sE-A)$ is not identically zero.

Therefore the result you state can be reformulated as: The regular system $(E,A,B)$ is completely controllable if and only if

- $\mathrm{rank}\left[sE-A \quad B \right]=n$ for all $s\in\mathbb{C}$, and
- $\mathrm{rank}\left[E \quad B \right]=n$.

The first condition states that the slow subsystem of $(E,A,B)$ is controllable, whereas the second one states that the fast subsystem is controllable.

We may ask the question of stabilizability. The system $(E,A,B)$ is said to be stabilizable if there exists a control law $u=Kx$ such that the system $(E,A+BK)$ is stable.

A necessary and sufficient condition for the regular system $(E,A,B)$ to be stabilizable is that

$$
\mathrm{rank}[sE-A\quad  B]=n\ \mathrm{for\ all\ }\Re[s]\ge0.
$$

Comment: A logical follow up question is what are the requirements for stabilizability? The first rank check changes from the entire complex plane to only the right half plane. But does the second rank check remain unchanged? I would assume so, since this results from the limit case of $\|s\| \to\infty$, so this evaluates both right and left half plane points, right?

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen Updated.